# The mapping which maps this region $\{z\in \mathbb C~:~0<Arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}\}$ onto the left half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

The angular domain in the complex plane is defined by $\{z\in \mathbb C~:~0<Arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{4}\}$, The mapping which maps this region onto the left half plane is

1. $w=z^4$
2. $w=-z^4$
3. $w=iz^4$
4. $w=-iz^4$

Since $Re(iz^4)=4xy(y^2-x^2)$ and the angular domain restricts $y<x$, we can eliminate option 4. Also i can eliminate 2 by taking a complex number $z_0$ with $Arg(z_0)=\frac{\pi}{6}$

How can we deal with 1st and 3rd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z^{4}$ maps the region to the upper half plane and you have to rotate it by an angle of $\pi /2$ to get the left have plane. So the answer is 3) since rotation by an angle of $\pi /2$ is same as multiplication by $e^{i\pi /2}=i$.

In fact the region you get in 1) 2) and 4)are precisely the upper half plane, the lower half plane and the right half plane.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at $1$, and using polar coordinates,  $z^4=r^4e^{4i\theta}$.  Thus the region is mapped onto $\{z\mid 0\le\operatorname {arg}z\le\pi\}$, the upper half plane.

The other three answers are rotations of $1$.  $3$, the rotation by $\dfrac {\pi}2$, is the one that works.